# C library function em Postgresql

Tags: c, postgresql, visual-studio

Estou usando Visual Studio 2015 para criar uma função em uma dll, e quando tento usa-la no Postgres, recebo a seguinte mensagem:

> server closed the connection unexpectedly
>       This probably means the server terminated abnormally
>       before or while processing the request.

Segue o código:

**C:**

**.c file:**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<math.h>

extern "C" {
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "sysmoroundtoabnt.h"
#include "utils/builtins.h"
#include "catalog/pg_type.h"
#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
    PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif
}

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(sysmoroundtoabnt);

Datum
sysmoroundtoabnt(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    PG_RETURN_INT32(10);
    //PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(10);
    //...
}
```

**.h file**

```
#ifndef SYSMOROUNDTOABNT_H
#define SYSMOROUNDTOABNT_H

#include "fmgr.h"

extern "C" __declspec(dllimport) Datum sysmoroundtoabnt(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

#endif
```

**Postgresql:**

```
create or replace function teste_victor( double precision, integer )
returns double precision
as '$libdir/sysmoroundtoabnt', 'sysmoroundtoabnt' language C;
```

**SQL Command**

```
select teste_victor(0.015, -2)
```

PS.: Se eu mudar no código em C, para retornar PG_RETURN_FLOAT8(10), o erro passa a ser este:

> invalid memory alloc request size 4294967290

Outra informação importante, é que o erro só acontece em Windows. Para Linux funciona perfeitamente, só preciso remover os `extern` dos arquivos `.c` e `.h`

O que há de errado com meu código?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Para resolver o problema:**

1. Remover `extern "C"` dos arquivos;
2. Colocar `PGDLLEXPORT Datum sysmoroundtoabnt(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)` no arquivo .h;
3. Trocar o `Double` por `Float8` e `Int` por `Int32` no arquivo .c;

Acredito que o problema principal era a forma que estava expondo meu método.
O crash no Postgres era devido ao superuso de memória, que era causado quando utilizava os tipos nativos ao invés dos sugeridos pela documentação do postgres.